# Force a script to continue running despite bringing up an error box

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that reads information from two different files, and writes output to a third file.  I have an error catch (the goal of the error catch is to display any IDs that did not get processed by the script) at the very end that uses a ctypes windows message box.  Currently, the script does not actually finish writing to the output file until I click "OK" on the error message box.  I would like the program to, instead, finish writing to the output file regardless of me pressing "OK".  Is this possible to do?

The script:

```
'''select newest reference file'''
directory = 'C:\User\Python test\Folder1'

newest = max(glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')), key=os.path.getctime)
timestamp = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d - %H_%M_%S")


'''Get IDS to be read'''

idlist = open('C:\User\Python test\ID List.txt').read().splitlines()

'''Print or write lines associated with selected IDS'''


output = open('C:\User\Python test\%s.txt' % timestamp, 'w')

with open(newest, 'r') as f:
    head = f.readline().strip()
    output.writelines(head + "\n")
    for referenceline in f.read().strip().split("\n"):
        for ids in idlist:
            if ids in referenceline:
                output.writelines(referenceline.replace(" ", "") + "\n")
                idlist.remove(ids)
text = '\n'.join(idlist)
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"%s" %text, u"IDs not found:", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one was pretty simple.  I just needed to close the file before the error catch.

Code:

```
output.close()
text = '\n'.join(idlist)
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"%s" %text, u"IDs not found:", 0)
```